# How to save screen output to a text file in Makefile

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I was using the original makefile to build my code with Perl scripts written in makefile.

Now I want to print all the log shown on screen to a txt file.

What command can I use in my makefile in order to do this?

I was meant to use some command in makefile to output what will be shown on screen to a txt file.
for example, if the makefile looks like:

```
all:

  perl filename.pl
```

how should I write in my makefile so that every time I type"make all" in command line, it will automatically save the output to a txt file?

Hi now I need to improve it, I need to save the output to a txt file whose directory should according to the input of my perl script.

For example, in the makefile:

all:

```
 $(X)make -C .. DIR=$(DIR) Y=$(Y) Z=$(Z)
 perl filename.pl $(DIR)/$(Y)/i.lst 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

how should I change in the makefile so that the log.txt will be saved at the directory equals the input $DIR? Ans I also want to change the name "log" to the input, how could I do this?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could pipe the output from stdout to a new textfile, right?  By the way, what do you mean by "the original makefile" -- the first makefile ever written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a make rule that invokes make recursively, redirecting things to a file:

```
all:
        $(MAKE) everything >log.txt

everything: ...whatever you had before for all
```

Of course, if you just have one command, you might as well put the redirection in there:

```
all:
        perl filename.pl >log.txt
```

If you want the output to both appear on the screen and be copied to the file, you can use `tee`:

```
all:
        perl filename.pl | tee log.txt
```

..and if you want to include stderr output in the file, you can redirect that too:

```
all:
        perl filename.pl 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Comment: thx so much! about the last one, when I use "2>&1", will the txt file contains both output and error message?

Comment: @user2962876: yes -- the magic incantation "2>&1" means "redirect output 2 (stderr) to the same place output 1 (stdout) is going"

Comment: @user2962876 Be sure to accept Chris' answer as "accepted" if it helped you out.  Given the additional details of wanting this to happen inside of a makefile, I believe it is superior to my answer. (+1)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Hi, thank you so much for the help! Could you please look at the new problem I got for the directory to save the log.txt?

Comment: @sonicgc: Not sure I understand your further question.  Do you just want to write the logfile to `$(DIR)/log.txt` (or `$(DIR)/$(Y).log`?) instead of `log.txt`?  If so just change it to the name and path you want to write to.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, piping the output from make to a text file should be pretty straightforward:

```
make > new_file.txt
```

Use two arrows instead if you want it to concatenate instead of replace each time:

```
make >> new_file.txt
```

Comment: thank you for this advice, but I was meant to use some command in makefile to output what will be shown on screen to a txt file. for example, if the makefile looks like:
all:
     perl filename.pl   
how should I write in my makefile so that every time I type"make all" in command line, it will automatically save the output to a txt file?